# Datasource for every control in GroupBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

Is something as this even possible. I'm pasting code bellow and hopping anyone could show me the right way to do it.

```
 For Each tbbox As TableLayoutPanel In GroupBox3.Controls
'looping through all controls in my tablelayoutpanle
            For Each ctl As Control In tbbox.Controls
                If ctl.Name.StartsWith("cb_barva") Then
'im stuck here...
                    With (ctl)
                        .DataSource = ds_barve.Tables("moje_barve")
                        .DisplayMember = "barva"
                        .ValueMember = "barva"
                        .SelectedIndex = 0
                    End With

                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: Are all the controls comboBoxes?

Comment: You have a set of controls in a table layout and you want to bind the same datasource to each one? It might be better to create a custom control with the settings you need and create a bunch of these at runtime.

Comment: The thing is i will like to populate all my comboboxes on a form with as little code as it gets. So i dont have to datasource every one of them with "with" clause.  I've tryed to bind items to them but the problem is that I then have 15 comboboxes with 1 binding source. And all of them change if I change selection in only one of them.

Comment: My advice - deal with each one separately.

Answer (score 1):

You need the type conversion

```
With (ctl)
```

Convert the ctl to ComboBox

```
ctype(ctl,ComboBox)
```

If your not able to convert the control with "With" statement then change each line of your code like below....

```
        ctype(ctl,ComboBox).DataSource = ds_barve.Tables("moje_barve")
        ctype(ctl,ComboBox).DisplayMember = "barva"
        ctype(ctl,ComboBox).ValueMember = "barva"
        ctype(ctl,ComboBox).SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: Did u mean: `With (ctl)
                        cttype(ctl, ComboBox)
                        .DataSource = ds_barve.Tables("moje_barve")
                        .DisplayMember = "barva"
                        .ValueMember = "barva"
                        .SelectedIndex = 0
                    End With`

Comment: But still...I cant manage to get it working...dunno where should I declare conversion that U did point me to.

Comment: Ty for Ur solution. But yet again I have problem, that if I change selection on one of them I get selected items on all of my comboboxes. Think that this should't happen with code mentioned.

Comment: Oh my god...................Use different datatables for deifferent comboboxes...... like  dt1 = ds_barve.Tables("moje_barve").Copy(). Becuase all comboboxes have the reference to same object.

Comment: =)...sry for me being so green...I've still have much to learn. As you see. But I'm very grateful for your help. Ty once more.